# Laravel 5.2 -> fill up tables on registration

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5

i have 2 accounts, business\company user and private user, they share some attributes as email,password,name. but there is a need to store more things about the businesses. so i have two tables.

main table: users
company: company is connected through Foreign Key(user_ID). 
So far i was not able to write anything into company table :/
any advice ?

**error i get**

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.companies' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `companies` (`ICO`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (15, 2016-01-30 18:38:28, 2016-01-30 18:38:28))
```

dont understant why it cant find table "companies"

**business model:**

```
class Company extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = ['ICO'];
        public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}}
```

**user model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname','middlename','lastname', 'email', 'password','usertype',];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];
    public function company(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company');
    }
}
```

**migration-company**

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('companyuser', function (Blueprint $table) {   
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('ICO');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');    
        });
    }
```

**AuthController.php**

```
   $user = User::create([
                        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
                        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
                        'middlename' => $data['middlename'],
                        'usertype' => $data['usertype'],
                        'email' => $data['email'],
                        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);
    //no problem with this upper part but with this part on bottom.
     $company = Company::create([
               'ICO' => $data[ICO],
           ]);
```

Comment: what error you get? give us more information

Comment: im sorry, edited original post.

Comment: You called the table companyuser not companies. Check phpmyadmin for the table name. Pretty obvious stuff

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if you have "companies" table.

Because you're creating "companyuser" table. But you don't have defined it in "Company" model.

Rename that table to **companies** or add `protected $table = "companyuser"`  to *\App\Company*

Comment: i found the problem. laravel creates table name by changing modal name to plural form. didnt know that.

Comment: Yup you are right. If you have User model then table name should be **users**. Otherwise you should define it in your model as I mentioned above